# How to bring a form to the current screen?

Tags: .net, winforms

there is this FormStartPosition but that seems to be only for showing first time.

Current screen is the one the mouse pointer is in. The form should appear top most. Setting the DesktopLocation on the form is too low level, I don't want to have to deal with all the possible desktop resolutions. It would be also nice that the form shows up at the center of the screen. That sort of functionality sounds pretty generic and should probably be in the windows api.

Comment: Do you want to set a form at TopMost?

Comment: Perhaps letting us know what platform you're working on, with what tool you are working shall help us. I know of a property from within Visual Studio while designing your form that perhaps should do it. The property is StartPosition, and the value is CenterScreen. So, you don't have to care about the resolution, Windows will deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Left and Top properties of the form to set its location, these positions are in relationship the whole visible area. You would need to write code to calcualate the position required.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps settings the StartPosition of the form on design time should do it. If you don't want to do it for all the other forms of your project, then derive this window to child windows.

Otherwise, we can't really understand what you're trying to do. A bit more precision and clarity on the subject could help us help you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you think of this, but I just thought about the BringToFront() method. This is generally mostly used within MDI applications.